# How to run two methods inside django models in parallel manner?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm incrementing two different fields in **User** models which are the **number of likes given to user's post** and **number of likes received by the user's post**. I did this through adding two methods in class model. It is working when I'm liking other posts but however, if I liked my own post it is not working. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Code snippet for user models

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    num_likes_received = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_dislikes_received = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_likes_given = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_dislikes_given = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    prediction = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def add_total_votes(self, vote):
        self.total_votes += vote
        self.save()

    def inc_num_likes_received(self):
        self.num_likes_received += 1
        print("1 like received")
        self.save()

    def inc_num_likes_given(self):
        self.num_likes_given += 1
        print("1 like given")
        self.save()
```

Code snippet for Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    num_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime_comments = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def add_num_likes(self):
        self.num_likes+=1
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Function for submitting like to certain post and at the same time this is where I executed the created two method from the models. (inc_num_likes_received and inc_num_likes_given)

```
def submit_like(request):

    User_PK = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    User_Give_Like = get_object_or_404(User, pk=User_PK.id)

    pk = request.POST.get('Status', None)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.add_num_likes()

    User_PK_Receive = User.objects.get(id=post.username.id)
    User_Receive_Like = get_object_or_404(User, pk=User_PK_Receive.id)

    LikeObject = Likes(username = User_Give_Like, post = post, liked=True, disliked=False)
    LikeObject.save()

    User_Give_Like.inc_num_likes_given()
    User_Receive_Like.inc_num_likes_received()

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

To become more specific these two lines of code below are the methods. The problem here is that the first line of code are not actually working but the last line are the only working. Whenever I rearranged these two lines of code the only executed was the last line of code.

```
    ....
    User_Give_Like.inc_num_likes_given()
    User_Receive_Like.inc_num_likes_received()
```

Example:

In this case, **User_Receive_Like.inc_num_likes_given()** are working but **User_Receive_Like.inc_num_likes_received()** are not working and vice-versa.

```
    ....
    User_Receive_Like.inc_num_likes_received()
    User_Give_Like.inc_num_likes_given()
```

The expected output is both fields **num_likes_given and num_likes_received** must incremented by 1.

Comment: Can you post your `Post` model? I suspect this line is the issue : `User_PK_Receive = User.objects.get(id=post.username.id)` but hard to tell without the model.

Comment: The question is now updated you may look for the Post model thanks.

Comment: OK, not what I was thinking then - it's just a little odd you called your user FK username :) Does the number of likes on the Post get updated correctly when `post-add_num_likes()` is called?

Comment: @urbanespaceman yes that line is working ```post-add_num_likes()```

Comment: Very odd situation .... are both your print statements coming out, regardless of which order you call those increment routines in? Also, which DB are you using? (Sqlite, postgres, other?)

Comment: Yes both are printing and I am using sqlite.

Comment: This is the output

[13/Aug/2019 16:56:53] "GET /admin/api/post/22/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6475
[13/Aug/2019 16:56:53] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3333
1 like received
1 like given

Comment: How are you verifying that they are not working?

Comment: I checked the django admin and the field is not updating, however, it is printing.

Comment: This has to be some kind of DB timing issue - that the call to the first save has not completed correctly when the second call is made. Not sure how to solve that - maybe with some kind of post_save signal? Side note: most social sites don't allow you to like your own posts - banning that would of course do away with the problem, but then that's not what you're asking :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look in to post_save signal.